# Call to undefined method App\Profile::create()

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is my migration table 
`create_profile_table.php`:

```
    <?php 

    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

    class CreateProfileTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->integer('userid')->unsigned()->default(0);
                $table->string('profilePic')->default('http://b2.com/Images/anup.jpg');
                $table->string('about',255);
                $table->foreign('userid')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::drop('profile');
        }
    }
```

This is my seeder file `ProfileSeeder.php`:

```
    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use App\Profile;

    class ProfileSeeder extends Seeder
    {

        public function run()
        {
             Profile::create(array('userid'=>1,'about'=>'Hello World'));
             Profile::create(array('userid'=>2,'about'=>'Hello World'));
             Profile::create(array('userid'=>3,'about'=>'Hello World'));
             Profile::create(array('userid'=>4,'about'=>'Hello World'));
             Profile::create(array('userid'=>5,'about'=>'Hello World'));
        }



    }
```

This is my model php file Model `Profile.php`:

```
    namespace App;


    class Profile
    {
         protected $table='profile';
         protected $fillable=['userid','about'];


    }
```

shows the error:

`[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Call to undefined method App\Profile::create()`

I am a new laravel5 Learner.

Don't know why this error is showing.

Any kind of help in this issue will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Profile`  class needs to extend the `Model` class if you want to be able to use the eloquent methods, like `create()`, `find()` and such.

You should use `php artisan`  to create your models, migrations, seeders and any other Laravel "component", they will work out of the box with minimal effort.

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Profile extends Model
{
     protected $table='profile';
     protected $fillable=['userid','about'];

}
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please consider marking it as the answer ;)